# Convert .pem file to .crt using Python3 OpenSLL

Tags: python-3.x, openssl, cryptography, pyopenssl, python-cryptography

I am new to SSL and trying to find some method or code which can convert .pem file to .crt using Python3 and OpenSSL.
Have searced through openSSL docs there is resource for shell script but wasn't able gain much python3..

Also I tried with some shell script

```
import os
cmd = 'openssl x509 -outform der -in cert.pem -out cert.pem.crt'
os.system(cmd)
```

but when I open the newly converted .crt file
i getting some gibberish words

instead of below words or encoding

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (certificate in base64 PEM encoding) ...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

If anyone can share some idea or code will be helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: File extensions historically have little meaning in the crypto world, so saying you have a .pem file and want to convert it to a .crt file tell us very little. Take a look at just a few of the [kinds of objects](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7468) that may be in a ".pem" file. Your openssl command seems to try to convert a PEM file to a der file, but then your comment expresses surprise that it doesn't look like a PEM file. Perhaps you can explain the where these files come from and what you want to use them in and why you think a conversion is necessary.

Comment: Just to give an example of what kind of explanation @PresidentJamesK.Polk is looking for: would it be a correct guess to presume your PEM-encoded file contains a key-pair, and you're looking to produce an X509 certificate for its public key?  If you update your question to indicate your *overall objective*, we can probably do a lot better job helping you to find and fit the right pieces together.  Also: don't get discouraged.  We've all had to work through 'what is ASN.1 vs. DER vs. PEM', and then you have to figure out what PEM-encoded ASN.1 structure an API expects...terrible.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk  thanks for the response and solution... I was actually trying to work on ** .pem ** file for ** aws iot thing ** with boto3. it needs three cerificates for authorization and validations in that one was .pem.crt file which I was able to bring using ** with statement  ** and it worked fine. thanks again to __lockcmpxchg8bI__ and learned some from your reference links...